# Display empty <p> with TextAngular at render

Tags: angularjs, editor, textangular

Is there an easy way to keep empty `<p>` visible in wysiwyg when using TextAngular?

If the string is `<h1>test</h1><p></p><p></p><h2>subtitle</h2>`, when the page render and the content is passed to TextAngular, the HTML source code has all tags, but the wysiwyg doesn't show them.

Did I miss something?
Thanks

Edit: [here is a fiddle to demonstrate](https://jsfiddle.net/L0cmszrz/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not an elegant solution, but you can parse your html string and add `&nbsp;` to your empty tags.

```
this.html = "<h1>Test</h1><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><h2>Test</h2>";
```

Comment: I saw that after a carriage return, it's not an empty `<p>` that is created but a `<p><br></p>`. Not sure if it's a feature or a bug.